# xmonad automatically switch to application

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I am very fond of xmonad, but one thing would be great:

If I open a file by `gvim -p --remote-tab-silent my-file` and it gets opened in vim which is always on `workspace 1`, I want to switch automatically to `workspace 1`.

I just discovered the [`viewShift`-trick](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/General_xmonad.hs_config_tips#Shift_an_app_to_a_workspace_and_view_it), but this only changes the workspace if a new `gvim` is spawned, and as such solves my problem just in part.

### Edit:

Thanks to Daniel Wagner's comment I was able to do some research:

I found a little program to set and unset urgency hints: [seturgency](http://www.codemadness.nl/blog/2010/10/31/seturgent-set-urgency-hints-for-x-applications/). And with `xwininifo` I can get gvim's window id. After some trial and error I `xprop` showed me that the hint flag was actually set.

```
GVIMWINID=`xwininfo -tree -root | grep GVIM | cut -d ' ' -f6`
seturgent $GVIMWINID 1
xprop -id $GVIMWINID | grep urgency
```

now i added

```
import XMonad.Hooks.UrgencyHook
..
 myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
[..
, ((mod4Mask             , xK_x      ), focusUrgent)
..]
..
main = do¬                                                                       
        xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar"¬                                   
        xmonad $ withUrgencyHook NoUrgencyHook $ defaultConfig {..}
```

to my [`.xmonad.hs`](https://gist.github.com/3014423), and `xmonad --recompile && xmonad --restart` was without errors but no hitting `mod4 + x` did nothing, though `xprop` did report the urgency hint is set.

Comment: A real answer would include code, but... can you get gvim to set an urgency notification and use the urgency hook to switch to that workspace?

Comment: thanks for the urgency tip - i edited what i found out.

Comment: Probably does not count as an answer, but your code actually works here. Note that you need to reset the layout (Mod-Shift-Space) and it seems to only pick up urgency hints that are set _after_ you restarted xmonad with the urgency hint.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - it seems that restart was necessary; what a pity I tried it for at least an hour to get it working - and just this was preventing me from enjoying my setup. Thanks

Comment: @DanielWagner can you put your comment on urgency hooks as an answer so i can award you the bounty i offered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comments by Daniel Wagner and Joachim Breitner I could solve the problem, at least in parts.

- Automatically switching to gvim if it is not opened yet simply works with adding to `myManageHooks

  ```
  myManageHook = composeAll [.., className =? "Gvim"--> viewShift "^ vim",..]
  ```
- if gvim is already open the situation is a bit more tricky, I've made a shell script to get the window id of gvim and see if there were arguments passed.

  ```
  #! /usr/bin/zsh

  GVIMWINID=`xwininfo -tree -root |grep GVIM | cut -d ' ' -f6`

  if [[ -n $GVIMWINID ]]; then
      #echo gvim is running
      #echo $GVIMWINID
      if [[ -n $@ ]]; then
          #echo there are args
          gvim -p --remote-tab-silent $@
      else
          #echo no args
          gvim --remote-send ":tabnew<cr>"
      fi
  else
      #echo gvim is not yet running
      #echo $GVIMWINID
      gvim -p $@
  fi
  seturgent $GVIMWINID 1
  ```

now if I spawn a new gv the window has its urgency hint set and I am able to switch to it.
But I wanted to switch automatically to the window - so at least if I spawn gvim by keyboard I want to switch automatically. So I added to `myKeys` in `xmonad.hs`

```
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $
[.., ((mod4Mask, xK_F1),
        spawn "gv" >>
        spawn "notify-send -t 500 -i /usr/share/pixmaps/vim-32.xpm gVim" >>
        focusUrgent),..]
```

Where the `spawn "notify-send .."` line acts as a timebuffer as spawning+setting urgency hint seems to take some time and `focusUrgent` is called too early.

The only unsolved thing is if I call my `gv`-script from the terminal to be switched to gvim's workspace.